# How i make text to change other image then user mouseover text

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover

So i want to make then someone mouseover text to change image(1st image) to other image(second), but then mouse is no longer on text image changes back to the first image(1st)

I have found somthing simmilar but its then you mouseover the image.
**HTML**

```
<a href="URL ADDRESS">
<img src="URL OF THE FIRST IMAGE GOES HERE" onmouseover="this.src='URL OF THE SECOND IMAGE GOES HERE'" onmouseout="this.src='URL OF THE FIRST IMAGE GOES HERE'" />
</a>

<a href="URL ADDRESS">
<img src="URL OF THE FIRST IMAGE GOES HERE" onmouseover="this.src='URL OF THE SECOND IMAGE GOES HERE'" onmouseout="this.src='URL OF THE FIRST IMAGE GOES HERE'" />
</a>
```

Comment: Bro this might attract lot of negative votes is this your first question ???

Comment: sorry i forgot to put that code 

 <a href="URL ADDRESS"><img src="URL OF THE FIRST IMAGE GOES HERE" onmouseover="this.src='URL OF THE SECOND IMAGE GOES HERE'" onmouseout="this.src='URL OF THE FIRST IMAGE GOES HERE'" /></a>

Comment: You have to show what you have tried, and where you got stuck. You cannot expect a ready solution

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rhsdtzoe/ here is the simplest implementation

Comment: I didint tried i am new with html :( but i searched for code really hard. Yes it is my first

Comment: seepo check this link https://jsfiddle.net/rhsdtzoe/  this is jsfiddle

Comment: i have to mouseover over the image not the text in your jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this with JavaScript or a JavaScript framework.

If you are looking for something like this: http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-1.html
Checkout out this jQuery plugin:
http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/#1

Here are some others:
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-image-galleries-sliders-best-of/

Answer (score 1):

Best (and fastest) way is to use CSS (assuming your html structure can support such solution).

For example:

**html**

```
<img class="class-show-hide" src="img1.jpg" />
<img class="class-hide-show" src="img2.jpg" />
```

**css**

```
img.class-show-hide
{
   display: inline-block;
}
img.class-hide-show
{
   display: none;
}
img.class-show-hide:hover
{
   display: none;
}
img.class-show-hide:hover + img.class-hide-show
{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

**bonus**

you can even add css transitions/animations to make for fancier effects, which would make a pure js solution slow, if not impossible

*update*

for the html example given, this solution can be applied as such:

```
<a href="a.url.here" class="hover-link">
<img class="class-show-hide" src="img1.jpg" />
<img class="class-hide-show" src="img2.jpg" />
</a>
```

**css**

```
a.hover-link
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
a.hover-link .class-show-hide
{
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   visibility: visible;
   z-index: 2;
}
a.hover-link .class-hide-show
{
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   visibility: hidden;
   z-index: 1;
}
a.hover-link:hover .class-show-hide
{
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}
a.hover-link:hover .class-hide-show
{
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**note:** in order to use text instead of second image then just use a

```
<span class="class-hide-show">text here</span>
```

element instead of second image and adjust css accordingly

[jsfiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/09mkzde4/1/)

Comment: @seepo, just use a `<span>` with text instead of second image

Comment: noo... i want to change the specific image at specific place. but how do i make text work with this css ? class=class-show-hide ? or how i dont get it :(

Comment: well :( for some reason images doesnt even appear

Comment: @seepo, ok let me prepare a jsfiddle

Comment: M, its shows a picture next to the text.What i want is to change already existing picture to another picture(i got 2 pictures both are same just colors diferent) sorry if i want too much.

Comment: @seepo, see [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/09mkzde4/), comment/uncomemnt second image or text fto use text or image, play with the css to achieve more effects or adjust for your use case

Comment: @seepo, accept the answer if it solves your problem, please

Comment: it doesnt i think its inpossible to make it in html then you mouseover text so its change already existing image

Comment: @seepo, no sorry wrong link, updating with corerct jsfiddle